# NavUp Button not working

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-actionbar, toolbar

I have a Main Activity which contains two Fragment **A(Tab1)** and **B(Tab2)**. From **B(Tab2)**, i have created a activity(CategoryBlogs). Now i want to go back from activity (CategoryBlogs) to Tab2. but when i presses the NavUp button on custom ActionBar , nothings happens

CategoryBlogs.java

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_category__blogs);
    listView = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);
    Toolbar tool_bar1 = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.tool_bar);
    setSupportActionBar(tool_bar1);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String message = intent.getStringExtra(Tab2.EXTRA_MESSAGE);
    String link = message.trim() + "?feed=titles";
    Log.d("ye category click krne par next activity me ye link bnta hy parsing ke liye",link);
    loadPage(link);
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_category__blogs, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    Log.d("hum option item selected me a gae", id+"");

    if(id==android.R.id.home){

        NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);
        Log.d("hum match kr gae", id+"");

        return true;
    }

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

AndroidManifest.XML

```
<activity
        android:name=".Category_Blogs"
        android:label="App For Blog" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="com.example.talha.test_fragement.MainActivity"
        />
    </activity>
</application>
```

Comment: check that you haven't `finish` main activity when u start `CategoryBlogs`

Comment: I just did, but it didn't help. I go to my Tab2 fragment and write finish() just after i pass the intent

Comment: have u try this getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

Comment: yes i did it in CategoryBlogs.java, not in Tab2 fragment

Comment: sorry i can't find setHomeButtonEnabled in your CategoryBlogs.java file pls double check it

Comment: as suggested `getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);` needs to be added for back button implementation to work..

Answer (score 0):

add in `onCreate`

`setHasOptionsMenu(true);`

and debug `onOptionsItemSelected` is it execute or not..

Answer (score 0):

You haven't specified the **android:parentActivityName** to which you are supposed to Navigate up in the **AndroidManifest.xml** file under **activity** tag.

```
android:parentActivityName="com.example.myfirstapp.MainActivity" >
```

Here's everything you need to know about **Navigating Up**

**1. Specify the Parent Activity in manifest.xml**

```
<activity
    android:name="com.example.myfirstapp.DisplayMessageActivity"
    android:label="@string/title_activity_display_message"
    android:parentActivityName="com.example.myfirstapp.MainActivity" >
    <!-- Parent activity meta-data to support 4.0 and lower -->
    <meta-data
        android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
        android:value="com.example.myfirstapp.MainActivity" />
</activity>
```

**2. Add Up Action in Activity (For the ActionBar <-)**

getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

**3. Navigate up to Parent by overriding onOptionsItemSelected() method**

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    // Respond to the action bar's Up/Home button
    case android.R.id.home:
        NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

For more information, follow this link http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/ancestral.html

Answer (score 0):

You have to get parent activity and
You have to replace this block of code -

```
NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);
```

with this:

```
Intent intent = NavUtils.getParentActivityIntent(this); //get parent activity
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP); 
NavUtils.navigateUpTo(this, intent); // and navigate your current activity to your parent activity
```

You've also tried to change the launchMode in the manifest at the `<activity>` element to

```
android:launchMode="singleTop"
```

or

```
android:launchMode="singleTask
```

There can be many solutions to solve your problem.